# Different Outputs of an Atoi Converted String-> int

Tags: c++, string, parsing, type-conversion

Here is my input file:

```
Plain Egg
1.45
Bacon and Egg
2.45
Muffin
0.99
French Toast
1.99
Fruit Basket
2.49
Cereal
0.69
Coffee
0.50
Tea
0.75
```

This is my code. I'm having no problem when people order 8 or 9 items, but as soon as they enter 10 or more items, I get really weird results and not the nicely printed check that I would like to see.  For instance, let's say someone orders 8 items and they input "12345678" for their order. I get this:

[image: Click Here For Nice Check]

But if the user inputs that they want let's say 15 items and they order "123456781234567", I get THIS:

[image: Click here for an ugly check]

Even when they order 10 items, I get just a blank check :/ :

[image: Click here for a blank check???]

What in the world is happening with my program? Does it have to do with me using c-strings? I want to understand what is going on inside my little computer and understand the way my computer thinks. If you can explain me this in a very simple way (I'm really new so I need something very explanatory with definitions of your fancy words) and some way I can understand, because like I said, I'm really new to computer science. Thank you.

```
    // Local Restaurant: The 5,000 Fed

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct menuItemType {
    string menuItem;
    double menuPrice;
};

void getData(menuItemType list[]);
string showMenu(menuItemType list[]);
void printCheck(string y, menuItemType list[]);

int main() {
    string y;

    menuItemType menuList[8];
    cout << "Hello and welcome to the 5,000 fed. Your local Long Beach café, "
                    "whose                 name is inspired by Jesus' miraculous manifestation "
                    "of bread to feed the 5k! His disciples helped him in passing out "
                    "the bread, and so I am here, your waiter, to help you and assist "
                    "you with your order. ";

    getData(menuList);
    y = showMenu(menuList);
    printCheck(y, menuList);

    return 0;
}

void getData(menuItemType list[]) {

    string menupricet[8];

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("menudata.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        getline(inFile, list[i].menuItem);
        getline(inFile, menupricet[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        list[i].menuPrice = atof(menupricet[i].c_str());
    }
}

string showMenu(menuItemType list[]) {

    int amount;
    char number;
    string reps;
    string response = "y";
    string total = "";

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Here is our wonderful menu. I do recommend the french toast, "
                    "similar to the bread that Jesus ate."
             << endl
             << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << setw(13) << left << list[i].menuItem << setw(8)
                 << right << list[i].menuPrice << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "How to order: Write the number you would like and specify how many "
                    "you want of that item by typing it in multiple times. For instance "
                    "an input of \"1135777\" means that you want two plain eggs, one "
                    "muffin, one fruit basket, and three coffees."
             << endl
             << endl;

    cout << "How many items are you ordering total?: ";
    cin >> amount;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please input your order, and press enter after your order: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        cin >> number;
        total += number;
    }

    return total;
}

void printCheck(string y, menuItemType list[]) {

    int k = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    double bill = 0;
    int newone = 0;

    k = atoi(y.c_str());

    while (k != 0) {
        newone = newone * 10;
        newone = newone + k % 10;
        k = k / 10;
    }

    cout << "Thank you for dining at the 5,000 fed. Here's your check:" << endl
             << endl
             << endl;

    cout << "_________________" << endl;

    while (newone > 0) {
        temp = newone % 10;
        newone /= 10;
        bill += list[temp - 1].menuPrice;

        cout << left << setw(15) << list[temp - 1].menuItem << right << setw(5)
                 << "|" << list[temp - 1].menuPrice << endl;
    }

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << left << setw(15) << "Amount Due:" << right << setw(10) << "|" << bill
             << endl
             << endl;
}
```

EDIT:
So someone asked me to paste the output as text instead of images so here are the three outputs:

They order 8 items such as "12345678":

```
_________________
Plain Egg          |1.45
Bacon and Egg      |2.45
Muffin             |0.99
French Toast       |1.99
Fruit Basket       |2.49
Cereal             |0.69
Coffee             |0.50
Tea                |0.75
Amount Due:             |11.31
```

They order 15 items such as "123456781234567":

```
_________________
French Toast       |1.99
\365\277\357\376^ޝ-        
  YW\300\365\277\357\376all\377
\200\367\277\357\376
\370\277\357\376
\227\370\277\357\376
\331\370\277\357\376%\371\277\357\376\262 
   |0.00
    Coffee             |0.50
    Muffin             |0.99
\362\277\357\376x\362\277\357\376x\362\277\357\376x\362\277\357\376Plain Egg33333    |0.00
Plain Egg          |1.45
Cereal             |0.69
\365\277\357\376^ޝ-YW\300\365\277\357\376all\377\200\367\277\357\376\370\277\357\376\227\370\277\357\376\331\370\277\357\376%\371\277\357\376\262    |0.00
Cereal             |0.69
Amount Due:             |6.31
```

They order 10 items such as "1234567812":

```
_________________
Amount Due:             |0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is associated with the size of the type `int`. Here is the solution, you may declare `k` and `new one` as `unsigned long int` so that they can hold up to `4,294,967,295` which still contains only 10 orders.

As a solution, you can use the `string y` as it is instead of converting to `int`. So that you can place as many orders as you wish. To traverse through the orders, you can use `substr` and `length` function of the `string`.

Let me re-write the `printCheck` function for, if I may

```
void printCheck(string y, menuItemType list[]) {
  double bill = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i< y.length(); i++)
  {
    string a = y.substr(i, 1);
    int kk = atoi(a.c_str());
    bill += list[kk - 1].menuPrice;

    cout << left << setw(15) << list[kk - 1].menuItem << right << setw(5)
             << "|" << list[kk - 1].menuPrice << endl;
  }
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
  cout << left << setw(15) << "Amount Due:" << right << setw(10) << "|" << bill << endl;
```

}

I hop this helps. Regards.

Comment: Are you sure about that range? That looks a lot like the range of `short` (except it is actually `-32768  to  32767`). Your `unsigned long int` is only correct for hardware that provides a 4-byte `unsigned long int`. (e.g. x86, not x86_64)

Comment: You think that's the only problem I have? Because if so, phew, I can get that over with and move on.

Comment: @LoveCoding I have less than 15 reputation, so I voted it up, but it does not display. Hey, by the way, I just have a new question. I am posting it up right now, if you could help me on it, I would be really thankful! I got a lot done on it, but am a little stuck. Please let me know if you can help, thanks!

Comment: @Alex sure, I'll try my best

Comment: Here it is @LoveCoding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540265/converting-roman-numerals-to-int-getting-the-wrong-output-why